# Unable to list available access points through `nmcli device wifi list` command on Debian and Pointlinux

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, nmcli

Pointlinux recognizes some wireless networks, but does not recognize certain one that has same Security as other recognized network (WPA1).I proved this with Fedora and Pointlinux writing in Terminal: `nmcli device wifi list`. This command, in Fedora displayes the network that interested me, but in Pointlinux does not, even if the signal is strong. Debian does the same.Please, have you an idea how to fix this problem? 
Thanks a lot.